# How to make Pervasive PDO PHP connection

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I am trying to establish a connection to my works Pervasive SQL database. I've tried using odbc_connect (didn't work) but I was told that PDO is easier and better (HA, also didn't work). This is my connection string
`$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=192.168.43.19;dbq=GLOBALTST");`

I've tried odbc:DSNname (https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.connection.php), ODBC:servername (ip and hostname), and odbc:databasename. Nothing has worked. This is the error I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IM003] SQLDriverConnect: 160 Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Pervasive ODBC Client Interface, C:\PSQL\bin\w3odbcci.dll). in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\default.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\default.php(4): PDO->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\default.php on line 4
```

The DLL it is looking for is actually located in the spot it's referencing. as far as I can tell there are no issues with it. THe ODBC is configured correctly on the server and I can connect to the DB in the PSQL control center. can anyone help in identifying my issue or pointing to a connection string that works either odbc_connect or PDO?

Comment: Is your PHP 32 or 64 bit?  What about IIS?  What about PSQL?  Usually the 1114 system error is caused by a 32/64 bit mismatch or a path problem.  Make sure the c:\psql\bin directory is in the system path.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me using PSQL v11 64 bit ODBC, PHP 7.2 64 bit on a Windows machine.

```
<?php
try {
    // Connect to the data source
    //$dbh = new PDO($dsn);
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Pervasive ODBC Interface};ServerName=192.168.43.19;dbq=demodata");

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM class');

    // Execute the prepared statement for each name in the array
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    $numResults = count($result);
    echo ('<b>Total Results: </b> ' . $numResults . '<br>');
    if ($numResults > 0) {
        // Output the table header
        echo '<table><tr>';
        foreach ($result[0] as $fieldName=>$value) {
            echo '<th>' . htmlspecialchars($fieldName) . '</th>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';

        // Now output all the results
        foreach($result as $row) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($row as $fieldName=>$value) {
                echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }

        // Close the table
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        echo 'No results';
    }
        

    // Close statement and data base connection
    $stmt = NULL;
    $dbh = NULL;
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```